# Why are my background colors not being displayed?

Tags: swing, scala, user-interface, background

Not sure why the color for my backgrounds aren't appearing?
I set opacity in each panel, do I have to do something else in the MainFrame contents portion?

```
// See http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/gui-programming.html
import scala.swing._
import java.awt.Color

object SecondSwingApp extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Second Swing App"

    val dealerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
      background = new java.awt.Color(35, 125, 35)
      preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 200)
      opaque = true
    }

    val botPlayerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
      background = new java.awt.Color(35, 125, 125)
      preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 200)
      opaque = true
    }

    val humanPlayerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
      background = new java.awt.Color(125, 125, 35)
      preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 200)
      opaque = true
    }

    contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
        contents += dealerPanel
        contents += botPlayerPanel
        contents += humanPlayerPanel
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's more a case of your inner boxpanels not being drawn at the size you want. If you try adding them to a `BorderPanel` instead then you see the right colours. I don't know if that's expected behaviour from a BoxLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Swing expert either, but it looks as if the panels take up no space if they don't have any content (as illustrated by another answer). The `preferredSize` is probably only relevant if the content would otherwise force the panel to exceed it's `preferredSize`. You can set `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` to the same value, thereby forcing the `BoxPanel` to take up that much space, but it of course makes the layout quite static.

[image]

```
val dealerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
  background = new java.awt.Color(35, 125, 35)
  // preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 200)
  minimumSize = new Dimension(100, 50)
  maximumSize = minimumSize
  opaque = true
}

val botPlayerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
  background = new java.awt.Color(35, 125, 125)
  preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 200)
  minimumSize = new Dimension(50, 100)
  maximumSize = minimumSize
  opaque = true
}

val humanPlayerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
  background = new java.awt.Color(125, 125, 35)
  // preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 200)
  minimumSize = new Dimension(200, 20)
  maximumSize = minimumSize
  opaque = true
}
```

Strangely, you still need to specify one of the `preferredSize` properties, because the window will otherwise not span over anything, all you see is the application's title bar.

Comment: This is a little more helpful than the other answer, as it illustrates how each of the size properties are actually used.  Static layout it an acceptable solution for now, as I'm just getting started and learning how all the swing stuff works with Scala.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because there are no Components int the dealerPanel, botPlayerPanel, and humanPlayerPanel so the background color does not display. If you add something to the each Panel, then the colors show up. For example, I added the label:

```
var label = new Label("dealer panel")
label.foreground = new java.awt.Color(255,255,255)
contents += label
```

[image]

There are issues with the size and layout as well that could be part of the problem.

```
import scala.swing._
import java.awt.Color

object SecondSwingApp extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Second Swing App"

    val dealerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
      background = new Color(35, 125, 35)
      preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 255)
      var label = new Label("dealer panel")
      label.foreground = new java.awt.Color(255,255,255)
      contents += label
      opaque = true
    }

    val botPlayerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
      background = new java.awt.Color(35, 125, 125)
      preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 255)
      var label = new Label("bot player panel")
      label.foreground = new java.awt.Color(255,255,255)
      contents += label
      opaque = true
    }

    val humanPlayerPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
      background = new java.awt.Color(125, 125, 35)
      preferredSize = new java.awt.Dimension(800, 255)
      var label = new Label("human player panel")
      label.foreground = new java.awt.Color(255,255,255)
      contents += label
      opaque = true
    }

    contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
        contents += dealerPanel
        contents += botPlayerPanel
        contents += humanPlayerPanel
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I get the same outcome when adding components to the panels.  Thanks!